# popoverTargetElement does not cross shadow boundaries

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, popover, shadow-dom

The new Popover API, when used declaratively, does not work across shadow boundaries. This is a limitation when creating reusable web components that encapsulate some logic and also use a `popover` internally while relying on external triggers in the light DOM.

According to [this explanaition from keithamus](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/9109#issuecomment-1494030465), it should be possible to connect a `popoverTarget` and a `popover` across the shadow boundary via the JavaScript API. I tried to test it, but my example does not seem to work:

```html
<test-popup>hello, this is a test</test-popup>
<button popovertarget="testpopup" id="shadow-popover-trigger">this should cross shadow boundaries and trigger a popup</button>
```

```js
const template = document.createElement("template");

template.innerHTML = `
  <div popover id="testpopup">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
`;

class TestPopup extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    const trigger = document.querySelector('[popovertarget="testpopup"]');
    const popover = this._shadowRoot.querySelector("[popover]");
    trigger.popoverTargetElement = popover;
  }
}

customElements.define("test-popup", TestPopup);
```

Is there an error in this implementation or is this not supported in Chrome 118? An example can also be found on codepen: https://codepen.io/tuelsch/pen/LYMvmva

Comment: May I refactor your code and make it a SO snippet?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `popover` ***inside*** shadowDOM to be triggered by a `button` ***outside*** shadowDOM

Note the Popover API isn't supported in FireFox yet (oct 2023)

It looks like the `beforetoggle` Event does not escape shadowDOM; maybe that is why I could not get the `.togglePopover()` method to work, it shows the popup but doesn't hide it.

Workaround then is to make the Web Component add a `click` eventListener (to the "outside" `<button>`) and do the `display:none/block` yourself.

Getting that button will need some extra work in a DOM with multiple shadowRoots. Maybe wrap the button in a Web Component and have it emit an Event that the popover Web Component listens for (on a custom EventBus or just `document`)

```html
<button id="B1">Toggle Popover inside shadowDOM</button>

<wc-popover id="P1" button="B1">I am a popover element</wc-popover>

<script>
  P1.addEventListener("beforetoggle", _ => console.log("beforetoggle P1"));

  customElements.define("wc-popover", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor( popopen = false ) {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
        .innerHTML = `<slot popover></slot>`;
      document
        .querySelector("#" + this.getAttribute("button"))
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
          this
            .shadowRoot.querySelector("[popover]")
            .style.display = (popopen = !popopen) ? "block" : "none";
        })
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using something like this myself at the moment. However, I'd very much like the browser to manage the visibility, event- and focus-handling of the popover - that's the point of the API.